# Simplistic AngularJS example (Error: [$injector:nomod], Error: [$injector:modulerr])

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to build simplistic and clear (for me) single-fiddle angular JS example and wrote something like

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');
    
var myControllers = angular.module('myControllers', []);

myControllers
  .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.watts = 735.5;
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        Watts:<input type="text" ng-model="watts"><br/>
    </div>
</body>
```

Unfortunetaly, it doesn't work and throws an exception.

Comment: you can simple change `ng-app="myApp"` to `ng-app="myControllers"`

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to put your controllers in a separate module you need to list that as a dependency for your main app.

```js
var myControllers = angular.module('myControllers', []);
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['myControllers']);

myControllers
  .controller('MyController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.watts = 735.5;
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    Watts:
    <input type="text" ng-model="watts">
    <br/>
  </div>
</body>
```